# Android Internet Permission not working while correct manifest

Tags: android, android-permissions

I thought i set up the android internet permission correctly, but i keep getting errors
What should i do to have it working?
Beneath is my error log and Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="nl.vlsolutions.buienl"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permissoin.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    <!--other things -->
</application>
```

Error log:

```
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-01 15:52:55.453: E/AndroidRuntime(31884): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

Comment: spelling mistake "android.permission.INTERNET"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo: `android.permissoin.INTERNET` should be `android.permission.INTERNET`

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to fix it for over 2 hours now!